# What is wrong with this code to calculate angles between vectors in R

Tags: r, function, error-handling, trigonometry, angle

My df is like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x1 = c(173L, 
185L, 190L, 231L, 267L, 185L, 190L, 233L, 260L), y1 = c(299L, 
321L, 360L, 361L, 377L, 321L, 360L, 363L, 309L), x2 = c(260L, 
230L, 230L, 172L, 233L, 230L, 231L, 267L, 260L), y2 = c(309L, 
322L, 322L, 378L, 363L, 322L, 391L, 377L, 309L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

> df
  ID  x1  y1  x2  y2
1  1 173 299 260 309
2  1 185 321 230 322
3  1 190 360 230 322
4  2 231 361 172 378
5  2 267 377 233 363
6  2 185 321 230 322
7  3 190 360 231 391
8  3 233 363 267 377
9  3 260 309 260 309
```

with this data, I want to calculate angles between vectors using myfun.

```
myfun <- function(x1, x2, y1, y2){
  xl <- x2-x1              # array of vectors in X
  yl <- y2-y1              # array of vectors in Y
  cl <- (xl^2 + yl^2)^0.5  
  atang <- atan2(yl, xl)   # angle in radians
  pi <- 3.142857
  angToDeg <- atang * 180/pi  # convert radians to degree
  if(angToDeg < 0){
    angToDeg <- angToDeg + 180
  }
  return(angToDeg)
}

df$ang = myfun(df$x1, df$x2, df$y1, df$y2))
```

I got following error:

```
Warning message:
In if (angToDeg < 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

How can I solve this error? and another things that I want to ask is 
that it is right to use 180 in the part with if() condition because I saw some people use 360 instead of 180 as following. Is it case specific or what?

```
  if(angle > 360){
    angle <- angle-360
  }
  return(angle)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `angToDeg[angToDeg < 0] <- angToDeg[angToDeg < 0] + 180`. Vectorized, no `if`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works. Can you give me a hint about what it is for. why do we need to do this part? I understood that it is compulsory step according to references in this site but I didn't get well why it is necessary for this calculation?